# Effective bit depth of mixed signals

Tags: audio, audio-processing, bitdepth

I have three signals of 16bit signed integers. Each signal represents a sine wave of unknown (and variable) frequency / phase in the audible range (20hz-20khz) and the amplitude is anywhere between `0` and `+/- i16::MAX`.

I'd like to mix these three signals into a single 16bit signal. I am wondering what the effective bitdepth of the signals becomes after mixing.

The safest way (no clipping) that I understand to do this is to add the three signals together in 32bits, and then bitshift twice:

```
fn mix(a: i16, b: i16, c: i16) -> i16 {
    let mixed: i32 = (a as i32) + (b as i32) + (c as i32); // potentially up to 18bits of data
    let shifted = mixed >> 2; // fit the data to 16bits
    return shifted as i16;
}
```

Since the signals are shifted, data is lost... does this mean my original signals are now effectively 14bit? Is there a better way to do this? I don't have access to time-based analysis (FFTs or average power measurements) since there are not enough cycles left on my microcontroller to do anything like that. If it's useful, I can limit the amplitude of the original signals.

Answer (score 1):

It would be enough to divide by three, but dividing by 4 might be faster as it can be just be shifted by two. And yes, if only one 16-bit sine channel is playing, it would make the resulting output sum to have 14 bits precision per channel. The signals could be generated with amplitude 10922 so three of them can just be summed together.

Comment: If it's a processor with native 32-bit words and a one-cycle multiply, then you could add them up, multiply by 0x5555 (that's 0x10000 / 3, truncated), then keep the upper 16 bits.  That's the same as multiplying by 0.3333282, so pretty near 1/3.  It's almost certainly faster than dividing by 3 (depending on your processor), and could be as fast as shifting down two bits (again, depending on your processor).